# Struggling with const behaviour when using vectors and iterators

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, constants

I'm having trouble with using vectors, iterators and then using `const`.

For a bit of context I'm trying to create a write method for a `vector<string>` so I can easily print out all the strings within the vector.

Here's the bit of code:

```
void ArrayStorage::write(ostream &sout) const{
    for (vector<string>::iterator stringIt = _dataVector.begin();
                    stringIt < _dataVector.end();
                    stringIt++){
        sout << *stringIt;
    }
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &sout, const ArrayStorage &rhs){
    rhs.write(sout);
    return sout;
}
```

When I try this I end up getting an error on line 2:

> cannot convert from '`std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>`' to '`std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>`'.

So I have to remove the `const` from the end of the write method, and then for the `operator<<` to work I have to remove the `const` from the rhs parameter.

Why is this? I am not trying to change any class members, so I don't understand what's going on... What is it I am missing?

Comment: Totonga's answer should be correct. In addition, your loop should usually look like this: for (vector<string>::iterator stringIt = _dataVector.begin(); stringIt **!=** _dataVector.end(); stringIt++){ ... } Usually only random access iterators support **<** or **>**.

Comment: Instead of hacking HTML into the post, please click the `?` button alongside the composition pane to learn how to format posts on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's like the compiler is telling you. Use

```
::const_iterator
```

instead of

```
::iterator
```

so

```
for (vector<string>::const_iterator stringIt = _dataVector.begin();
                stringIt != _dataVector.end();
                ++stringIt){
    sout << *stringIt;
}
```

would work. Make sure to use != instead of < when comparing to end().

Comment: I feel so stupid... just after I posted this I figured where I was going wrong!

Thanks.